# Event when image size is known - JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for event when appended by JS image has known height (not fully image loaded).
This event should occurs between `$('img').ready()` and `$('img').load()`.

You can find example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrxtk5pk/) - I'm simulating this event in setInterval loop (when height is known).

Example results from this fiddle (image should not be cached by browser): 
time after append: 6ms, height: unknown. (ready event)
**time in loop: 259ms, height: known. (??? event)**
 
time on load event: 3884ms, height: known (load event).

PS. I'm appending form ajax bunch of html content and I want to animate it - height is essential for it. The best solution will be when: I will have event on outside container firing when all images have known height (it will not change size in time).

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan look at the 27 line: `$('#placeForImg img').load(function() { ... });` - I've specially added this big image to underline that this is not the best way to solve my problem (too much time to wait).